# Xamarin.Forms App crash on iOS after updating to 13.1

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, core-animation, ios13

I was using Visual Studio 2017 with Visual Studio 2017 on mac. Mono version was 5.18.1 and Xamarin.iOS version was 12.4 (I think). The app worked fine without any problem. Recently I have updated Visual Studios on both Windows and Mac to 2019 and Xamarin.iOS version have updated to 13.4. Now the app is having 'weird' crashes on both Simulators and on iPhone with iOS 13.1. But on simulators with iOS 12.4, the app works smoothly. Also, the released app in the app store (build with Xamarin.iOS 12.4) works fine as expected in iOS 13.1 devices.

The app seems to be crashing when doing some work related to animation, and here's the crash log from AppCenter.

```
Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'SIGABRT', reason: 'Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread after it has been accessed from the main thread.
Native stack trace:

**some native trace**

Xamarin Exception Stack:
Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread after it has been accessed from the main thread.
Native stack trace:

**some native trace**

at ObjCRuntime.Runtime.ThrowNSException (System.IntPtr ns_exception) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.4.0.2/src/Xamarin.iOS/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:406
  at ObjCRuntime.Runtime.throw_ns_exception (System.IntPtr exc) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/runtime/Delegates.generated.cs:128
  at (wrapper native-to-managed) ObjCRuntime.Runtime.throw_ns_exception(intptr)
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) ObjCRuntime.Messaging.void_objc_msgSendSuper(intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIView.LayoutSubviews () [0x00023] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.4.0.2/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIView.g.cs:1290
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].LayoutSubviews () [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementRenderer.cs:289
  at null.null
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) ObjCRuntime.Messaging.void_objc_msgSendSuper(intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIView.LayoutSubviews () [0x00023] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.4.0.2/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIView.g.cs:1290
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].LayoutSubviews () [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementRenderer.cs:289
  at null.null
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) ObjCRuntime.Messaging.void_objc_msgSend(intptr,intptr)
  at CoreAnimation.CATransaction.Commit () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.4.0.2/src/Xamarin.iOS/CATransaction.g.cs:90
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.CADisplayLinkTicker.StartThread () [0x0003a] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\CADisplayLinkTicker.cs:61
  at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context (System.Object state) [0x00014] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/thread.cs:74
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00071] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:968
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:910
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state) [0x0002b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:899
  at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart () [0x00008] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/thread.cs:111
```

Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem here? :(

Comment: That probably means you are updating some UI in a background thread or something similar. Can you debug your code to see where the crash happens and check if you are updating UI there. You can use `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ });` to run code in Main thread.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT debugging didn't help. Crashes that happened during debugging, didn't reproduce when I opened the app without attaching the debugger. It was weird.

Comment: Crashes that happened during debugging, so can you know in which page it crashed? Check the code there.

Comment: The code sample in the above comment is for Obj-C. In Xamarin.Forms, use the following to guarantee code is run on the UI/Main thread: `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(Action)` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.device.begininvokeonmainthread?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: I have checked all the code with a helper class to check if the current thread is the main thread or not. But all the places related to the crash were on the main thread. So it wasn't me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow when I removed `Xamarin.Forms.Editor` from the views related to the crash, no crash happened. I thought If my code wasn't doing something, then probably the renderer (EditorRenderer) might responsible for updating UI on a background thread or something. So I updated the `Xamarin.Forms` version a bit, and it worked.

So updating Xamarin.Forms version to 3.6 resolved the issue!

Comment: I encountered this same crash on 4.3.0.851321-pre3.

Comment: There were lot of crashes similar to this! You could find more of those on https://forums.xamarin.com/ & https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/ .
In my case, the app crashed when it was doing some Animation stuff.

Comment: I am using version 4.4.0.9 facing this issue.

Comment: @SufyanAhmad If you could find which page/view causing the crash, I suggest that removing/adding controls one by one until you find which control responsible for the crash. That was my method of identifying that the Editor was responsible for the crash.